# Maps between Module Tensor Products

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $M\otimes N$, $M'\otimes N'$ be R-modules, R commutative ring. My question is, must any homomorphism $M\otimes N\to M'\otimes N'$ be of the form $f\otimes g$, where $f:M\to M'$ and $g:N\to N'$ ? I am new to tensor products, so the answer to this question might be obvious to some of you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try working with the $\mathbb{R}$-modules (vector spaces) $M = N = M' = N' = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Further hint:

> You will notice that $M \otimes N \cong \mathbb{R}^4$ with homomorphisms $h : M \otimes N \to M' \otimes N'$
>  corresponding to $4\times 4$ matrices, which have 16 degrees of freedom, while maps $f \otimes g$ with
>  $f : M \to M'$ and $g : N \to N'$ correspond to two $2 \times 2$ matrices put together, amounting
>  only to 8 degrees of freedom. There must therefore be maps $h$ which cannot be written as
>  $f \otimes g$. You might for instance try the almost-identity matrix
>  $$ h = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \,. $$
>  Let me know if any steps are unclear.